# Platform specific for h1,h2,h3 etc tags

Tags: react-native, styled-components

How do I write to have a specific tag for specific platform?

I know it goes something like this ...`Platform.OS === 'ios' ? h2 : h3`

But how to do label it?

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way this can be achieved is;

**Method 1**

```
var {Platform} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    fontSize: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 18 : 22
});
```

**Method 2**

```
 {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <H1>{'iOS'}</H1}
 {Platform.OS === 'android' && <H2>{'Android'}</H2}
```

**Method 3**

```
 <Text style={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? styles.android_style : styles.ios_style}>
```

There is other ways but these come to mind first.  I'd suggest method 1 as it's a nice, clean solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I agree Method 1 is cleaner. But how do you write it to choose between h2 : h1?

Comment: I updated method 2 to show an example.  Not very clean but it'd work. I am sure there is alternative ways that are cleaner.